# radio selected/unselected based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the thing:

I have dropdown list with 3+ options, and yes/no radio group. What i need is to set radio "no" checked when option 1 is selected and radio "yes" when others are selected.

Here is the code:

```
<select id="exp_days" name="exp_days">
<?php                   
    foreach($this->days as $day){
        echo '<option value="'.$day->days.'"';  
            if($day->days==$exp_days){
                echo ' SELECTED ';  
            }                           
            echo '>';

            if($day->days==1){
                echo $day->days.'&nbsp;'.'DAY';
            }else{
                echo $day->days.'&nbsp;'.'DAYS';    
            } 

            if($day->price !='0.00'){
                //echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$day->price.'&nbsp;'.$par->get('unit_price');    
                echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.priceFormat($day->price,$par->get('unit_price'));
            }
        echo '</option>';
    }
?>
```

```
<input type="radio" name="p_first" value="1" checked="checked"/><label>YES</label>
<input type="radio" name="p_first" value="0"/><label>NO</label>
```

Comment: I certainly don't want to be rude or anything, but what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe you could try some javascript/JQuery and post what you tried later??

Comment: Apart from having value=1 option twice in your select, do you want to set the radios after POST, or with javascript?

Comment: value is autogenerated by php. javascript is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
<script>
    function change(select){
        if(select.selectedIndex === 0){
            document.getElementById('radio1').checked=true;
            document.getElementById('radio2').checked=false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('radio2').checked=true
            document.getElementById('radio1').checked=false;
        }

    }

    </script>



    <select id="exp_days" name="exp_days" onchange="change(this)">
<?php                   
    foreach($this->days as $day){
        echo '<option value="'.$day->days.'"';  
            if($day->days==$exp_days){
                echo ' SELECTED ';  
            }                           
            echo '>';

            if($day->days==1){
                echo $day->days.'&nbsp;'.'DAY';
            }else{
                echo $day->days.'&nbsp;'.'DAYS';    
            } 

            if($day->price !='0.00'){
                echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.priceFormat($day->price,$par->get('unit_price'));
            }
        echo '</option>';
    }
?>


    <input type="radio" name="p_first" id="radio1" value="1" checked="checked"/><label>YES</label>
    <input type="radio" name="p_bg" id="radio2" value="0"/><label>NO</label>
```

working fiddle showing what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vDHV7/1/